# options in R ggplot2 package a.(show values in x axis passed through aes() ), b.(regression eqn on the top right side)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, regression

I have generated the following regression plot

[image: Refer to the snap here that I've currently]

by the code

```r
ggplot(data, aes(x=EDUCLVL , y=CUMDOSE)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method="lm", col="black") +
    stat_regline_equation() +
    theme_bw()
```

I need help in 2 aspects.

1. In my x-axis I've values 5,6,10,11,12,15,16,17,18,20,21,22,23,24,25.I would like to show all the values in the x-axis, but R takes only 5 values randomly with a gap of 5, any option to get all the values somehow(irrespective of clarity or size).
2. The regression equation comes at the top left corner, I would like to place it at the top right corner, any option available to define the equation at the side of choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't posted your data, but here is a solution using `mtcars` that you can tweak to your needs.:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg , y=cyl)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", col="black") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = round(seq(min(mtcars$mpg), max(mtcars$mpg), by = 2),1)) +
  stat_regline_equation(label.x = 28, label.y = 9) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: ggplot-output]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a another approach. It sets the x axis breaks to the specific unique values in `EDUCLVL`. The parameters `label.x.npc` and `label.y.npc` set the relative position of the equation along each axis, where 0 is for bottom/left and 1 is for top/right. These parameters also accept character values like "top" and "centre".

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=EDUCLVL , y=CUMDOSE)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", col="black") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = unique(sort(data$EDUCLVL))) + 
  stat_regline_equation(label.x.npc = 0.8, label.y.npc =  1) +
  theme_bw()
```